# Application Users and End Users using ASP.NET Core Identity

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, authorization, asp.net-identity

I am creating a new application that will have a CMS for Admin users and a front-end for end users.  I am struggling with how to implement these 2 user types in my application.  Should both these users be stored in the same AspNetUser table?  Or should they be distinguished by claims and/or discriminator value?  What about Authorize attributes, I want Admin Users to to be redirected to the admin login page. And I want end users to be redirected to the frontend member login page.

AdminUserDataModel.cs

```
public class AdminUserDataModel : IdentityUser
{
}
```

EndUserDataModel.cs

```
public class EndUserDataModel : IdentityUser
{
}
```

Program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddIdentity<AdminUserDataModel, IdentityRole>(options =>
{
    options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true;
}).AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationUserContext>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();


builder.Services.AddIdentityCore<EndUserDataModel>(options =>
{
    options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true;
}).AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationUserContext>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

Answer (score 0):

I can get your point, But in `Asp.Net Core identity`, All the other core components of Identity (roles, claims, logins, etc.) are setup with foreign keys to one user table. So I'm afraid you can't have multiple `identityUser` tables.

For your scenario here, you should use inheritance. For example:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser{....}

public class AdminUser : ApplicationUser{....}

public class EndUser : ApplicationUser{....}
```

Then configure it in `Startup.cs` like:

```
services.AddIdentityCore<AdminUser>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppDbContext>();
services.AddIdentityCore<EndUser>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppDbContext>();
```

Add `Dbset<AdminUser>` and `Dbset<EndUser>` in `AppDbContext`.

In Controller, You can inject `UserManager<AdminUser>` and `UserManager<EndUser>` to create different Users.

Comment: Hi, @user2127521, If this answer help you solve the problem, Can you mark it as an answer? Thank you very much!